# How to get Flow to properly work with Vue 2 (webpack)?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, flowtype

I'm trying to add [Flow](https://flowtype.org) to the Vue 2 webpack-template. For the record, I'm on runtime-only (files follow the `.vue` format / standard).

My first attempt was to use flow through the cli, which I realized it's not going to work because it didn't know how to handle `.vue` files.

My second attempt was to add a webpack loader (namely  [flow-status-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/diegodurli/flow-status-webpack-plugin)) and run Flow check as part of the build (like `eslint` works for example). That didn't work out, so I looked into other options.

My third attempt was to use a babel plugin, which was fairly successful at first. I used [babel-plugin-typecheck](https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck) + [babel-plugin-syntax-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-syntax-flow). There's no output in Webpack, however a type error would break the app. I'm fine with this approach; it'll work fine with a CI and break the build.

Here's how my `.babelrc` looked:

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    ...
    ["typecheck", {
      "disable": {
        "production": true
      }
    }],
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ],
  ...
}
```

At this point, Flow works as expected for global methods, but doesn't work inside a Vue component:

```
<template>...</template>

<script>
/* @flow */
const flowIt = (a: number): number => {
  return a * 10
}

flowIt(20)
flowIt('bah') // Uncaught TypeError: Value of argument "a" violates contract. Expected: number Got: string

export default {    
  mounted: function () {
    flowIt(20)
    flowIt('bah') // Sees nothing wrong here
  }
}
</script>

<style>...</style>
```

On top of that, the goal is to not change the app code because of Flow. Ideally, I'd just use Vue as normally:

```
<template>...</template>

<script>
/* @flow */
export default {  
  methods: {
    flowIt (a: number): number {
      return a * 10
    }
  },

  mounted: function () {
    this.flowIt(20)
    this.flowIt('bah') // Should throw a type error.
  }
}
</script>

<style>...</style>
```

Not sure if this has that much to do with Vue as it has with my experience with Flow (hint: not that experienced). I'm thinking I need some type files that make Flow 'understand' how a Vue component is structured (same for directives I guess).

To those that have more experience with it, how did you get Flow to properly work with Vue + webpack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use Flow for the JS portion of a .vue component, by commenting out the `<template>`, `<style>` and `<script>` portions:

```
 /* @flow
 <style>
 ...style definitions here
 </style>
 <template>
 ...html...
 </template>
 */
 // <script>
 export default {  
   methods: {
      flowIt (a: number): number {
         return a * 10
      }
   },

   mounted: function () {
      this.flowIt(20)
      this.flowIt('bah') //Won't throw error, as flowIt is attached to
                         //this.
   }
}
// </script>
```

The vue compiler will still recognize the `<template>, <style> and <script>` sections even when commented, but the Flow type checker will ignore them and only process the proper javascript section.

Unfortunately, this won't get you 100% type coverage, as Flow will not be able to check functions and objects attached to `this` (the Vue component itself), however, you can still benefit from Flow's type checking of calls out to external functions (e.g. Vuex actions and getters, other javascript imported modules), and if you have extended business logic within the component's methods, you can get some type safety when working with the method parameters.

Comment: That's a bummer. I was hoping there is a way to get 100% coverage, perhaps some Flow annotation magic, but I am starting to believe there isn't. Regarding commenting out those sections, with babel-plugin-typecheck there's no need to comment out the template & style, because it only checks what's inside the script. It does work a lot differently than a flow webpack plugin or running flow through the CLI, but so far I had no issues.

Comment: I'll give it a couple more days, if there's no other suggestion on how to achieve this, I'll accept your answer :-)

Comment: Alright @Nik. Managed to get it going as I initially wanted with a runtime check via [babel-plugin-tcomb](https://github.com/gcanti/babel-plugin-tcomb) during development + `flow check` as part of the CI. Wrote up my config in a new answer; maybe it'll help others. I'll keep yours as accepted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

### Using eslint + flow

This is yet another approach to integrating flow & vue.
Meanwhile, `flow` came to `eslint`. Therefore, we can get flow errors straight as lint errors. It's a cleaner approach, but then flow becomes coupled with your build process (you can't run `flow check` independently, but need to run your entire build pipeline via webpack to get the errors). Still waiting for [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2218) to be resolved to have full flow support in `.vue` files as of *10th of May 2017*.

For most cases that's fine, but some might still want the flexibility (and speed) of running `flow check`. That might also depend on your CI setup.

Here's how you can setup flow and eslint:

1. Install deps

   ```
   yarn add \
     babel-plugin-syntax-flow \
     babel-plugin-transform-class-properties \
     babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types \
     eslint \
     babel-eslint \
     eslint-plugin-html \
     eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors \
     eslint-plugin-vue \
     eslint-config-vue \
     flow-bin \
   -D
   ```
2. Configure `.babelrc`

   ```
   {
     ...
     "plugins": [
       "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
       "babel-plugin-syntax-flow",
       "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Configure `.eslintrc`

   ```
   {
     "parser": "babel-eslint",

     "plugins": [
       "html",
       "flowtype-errors"
     ],

     "extends": [
       "vue"
     ],

     "rules": {
       "flowtype-errors/show-errors": 2
     }
   }
   ```
4. Create a `.flowconfig` file. It can be empty if you have nothing to configure.

No other workarounds required in this case, you can then just use `/* @flow */` in the script tags in any of your `.vue` files.
See the original post [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/components-flow/).

Comment: I cant get this to work. I went all-in and reinstalled Atom to make sure evertyhing is setup correctly but I still cannot get any errors to display inside my Vue components. If I force Atom to parse it as a javascript file it works though. Hmmm.. What editor are you using? using linter-eslint package to support ESLint. Any thoughts ? Would be really sweet to get it up.

Comment: Got it working! I had to activate the linter-eslint package to "Lint HTML files" as that will activate linting of the .vue files.

Comment: Awesome. Got it working both in Sublime in Atom (for reference). Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Nik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111432/3263450), it's worth mentioning that combining his 'comment' strategy with a runtime checker makes 'the package' a tad more complete. 
One way to do it is by using [babel-plugin-tcomb](https://github.com/gcanti/babel-plugin-tcomb). That'll make the runtime checker part of the webpack / build process (on save) + `flow check` as part of a CI script.

For development, tcomb will do a runtime check and will throw an exception (console). It doesn't do static checks, so the following

```
<script>
/* @flow */
const flowIt = (a: number): number => {
  return '' // Sees nothing wrong here, should be a number
}

// Vue component
export default {    
  ...
}
</script>
```

won't work as expected. However, the following will:

```
<template>{{ foo('bar') }} <!-- Type error --></template>
<script>
/* @flow */
const flowIt = (a: number): number => {
  return '' // Type error
}

// Vue component
export default {    
  methods: {
    foo: (x) => { flowIt(x) // Type error }
  },

  mounted: () => {
    flowIt([]) // Type error
  }
}
</script>
```

That's not ideal, but it does check after each save and that'll catch most type errors.
Worth mentioning: tcomb uses the same annotations (uses Flow internally), so it works out of the box.

Ofc, that's not good enough & kinda defeats the point of Flow. The solution to that is to still run `flow check` on the CI, as mentioned. That requires a number of changes:

1. Update .flowconfig to load .vue files:

   ```
   ...
   [options]
   module.file_ext=.vue
   module.file_ext=.js
   ...
   ```
2. Include the template & style block in the comment containing the @flow pragma; comment out the script tags (this approach was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105053/how-to-get-flow-to-properly-work-with-vue-2-webpack/)):

   ```
   /* @flow
   <template>...</template>

   <style>...</style>
   */

   // <script>
   ...
   // </script>
   ```

   That's a bit awkward, but I could not find a better way. Ideally, Flow would be able to process `<script>` tags in a HTML doc, but that's just on the wishlist for now ([see issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2218)).
3. Disable tcomb in production

   ```
   {
     ...
     "plugins": [
       ...
       "syntax-flow",
       "transform-flow-strip-types"
     ],
     "env": {
       "development": {
         "plugins": ["tcomb"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: question: If I would structure my components at the beginning like in this [vue 2.0 boilerplate example](https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2.0-boilerplate/tree/master/src/app/pages/login/index) where .vue only loads external .js and .html and let flow cli ignore .vue and only check .js it could also work without ugly modifications (because it is seperated at the beginning). What do you think?

Comment: Yes it should be fine. Vue files won't be checked by default unless you explicitly state that in the flow config file.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been solved in the meantime and now you can use Flow with Vue-components without hacks. See this rather brilliant article for config details:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/components-flow/

Comment: Hey @musicformellons. That's yet another way to do it, but beware that `flow check` won't work if you choose the eslint approach. See [detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43889279/3263450). Still, a valid approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a project template for `vue` with `flow`. https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template It supports single file components, linting, tests with `jest`, building, and server side rendering.

### vue

Here's what your components would look like:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
// @flow

import Vue from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import { Getter, State } from 'vuex-class'
import AppLogo from '~/components/AppLogo'
import Comment from '~/components/Comment'
import type { CommentType, StateType } from '~/types'

@Component({
  components: {
    AppLogo,
    Comment
  }
})
export default class Index extends Vue {
  @State('comments') comments: Array<CommentType>
  @Getter('hasComments') hasComments: boolean

  fetch (
    { store, app }: { store: Store<StateType>, app: Vue }
  ): Promise<Array<CommentType>> {
    // Uncomment the next line to test flow types:
    // console.log(this.comments + 12)
    return store.dispatch('fetchComments', app)
  }
}
</script>
```

It requires several things to configure:

1. Dependencies. Everything with `flow` in its name from here: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/package.json
2. Creating valid `.flowconfig`. This might be tricky: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/.flowconfig
3. Configuring `.babelrc`: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/.babelrc
4. Configuring `eslint`: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/.eslintrc
5. Triggering `flow-typed install` after each normal installation: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/package.json#L12

### vuex

You are also able to annotate `vuex` store: state, commit handlers, getters, and actions. You can use [`@vue-flow-typed/vuex`](https://github.com/sobolevn/vue-flow-typed) for this part.

That's how it looks:

```
type StateType = {
  comments: string[]
}

function state (): StateType {
  return {
    comments: null
  }
}

const getters = {
  hasComments (state: StateType): boolean {
    return Boolean(state.comments && state.comments.length > 0)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  'SET_COMMENTS': (
    state: StateType, comments: string[]
  ) => {
    state.comments = comments
  }
}

const actions = {
  async fetchComments (
    { commit, state }: ActionContext<StateType>
  ) {
    const data = await Promise.resolve(['good', 'nice'])
    commit('SET_COMMENTS', data)
    // Uncomment next line to see typing in action:
    // console.log(state.comments, state.fake)

    return data
  }
}
```

But beware, that it is still impossible to annotate some parts. 
Read more about known issues here: https://github.com/sobolevn/vue-flow-typed#known-problems